# Proving that $Y\setminus B = (X \setminus O) \cap Y$ if $B=O \cap Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $ Y \subseteq X$. Let $O \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$.

> Then is it true that if $B=O \cap Y$, then is it true that $Y\setminus B = (X \setminus O) \cap Y$?

I made a proof for this but I'm now sure if it is correct or not.

---

#### My proof

**Part 1**

Let $x \in Y\setminus B$, then we know that $x \in Y \wedge x \notin B$. (1)

Because $ x \notin B$ and we know that $B = O \cap Y$, then $x \notin O \cap Y$. From (1) we know that $x \in Y$ so we must have that $x \notin O$, thus $x \in X \setminus O$ (2).

From (1) and (2), we know that $x \in Y \wedge x \in X \setminus O$, so $x \in (X\setminus O) \cap Y$.

So we have that $Y \setminus B \subseteq (X\setminus O) \cap Y$.

**Part 2**

Now let $x \in (X\setminus O) \cap Y$. Then $x \in Y \wedge x \in X\setminus O$. This means that $x \in Y \wedge x \notin O$. But we have that $B = O \cap Y$, so $x \notin B$. As $x \in Y \wedge x \notin B$, we can conclude that $x \in Y\setminus B$.

Thus $Y \setminus B \supseteq (X\setminus O) \cap Y$

**Conclution**

We have that $Y \setminus B \subseteq (X\setminus O) \cap Y$ and $Y \setminus B \supseteq (X\setminus O) \cap Y$, so we conclude that $Y\setminus B = (X \setminus O) \cap Y$.

---

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Take any example where $Y$ is  a proper subset of $X$ and  $B=O \cap Y$ is empty. Then your equation becomes $Y=X$ which is not true.

Specific example: $X=\mathbb R, Y=(0,1), O=(1,2)$ and $B=\emptyset$.

In fact any point $x \in X \setminus Y$ belongs to RHS and  not to LHS. So the result cannot be true unless $X=Y$.

PS: I have realized that parenthesis is missing in your notations. With the correction I suggested in one of my comments below the equation is true and what you have done is fine.

Comment: Then with some restrictions can this be true?

Comment: No, this is false unless $Y=X$.  @EduardoMagalhães

Comment: Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $Y = \{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Let $O = \{6,7,8,9\}$. Then $B = O \cap Y = \{6,7\}$. $Y \setminus B = \{2,3,4,5\}$. $X \setminus O \cap Y = \{1,2,3,4,5,10\} \cap \{2,3,4,5,6,7\} = \{2,3,4,5\} = Y \setminus B$. Thus $Y \setminus B = X \setminus O \cap Y$ and $X \neq Y$

Comment: This is an counter example for what you just stated

Comment: Check again. $1 \in X \setminus O\cap Y$.

Comment: How can that be possible if $1 \notin Y$?

Comment: when I say $X \setminus O \cap Y$ I mean, $(X\setminus O) \cap Y$ did you interpreted that way?

Comment: I think there is some problem with your notations. You might have typed $X \setminus O\cap Y$ for $(X\setminus O) \cap Y$. That is ambiguous.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit the post